# Somar valores da coluna criada no PIVOT

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, oracle

Bom, nessa query eu tenho que listar os produtos que saíram para consumo em um determinado período, e o quanto foi consumido de cada produto. Tenho o cód do produto, nome, data da movimentação, a quantidade que foi consumida e a quantidade em estoque (somatória de todos os estoques). Porém existe algumas considerações.. existem 2 tipos de saída de produto, a saída para paciente que é (P) e saída para setor que é (S), e isso encontra-se em tp_mvto_estoque. O (c) e (d) é devolução, uma de setor e outra de paciente.. O estoque atual já é a soma dos produtos em todos os estoques.. Porém preciso somar as duas saídas que são S e P e subtrair pela soma das devoluções que são C e D.. S+P-C+D, Tentei realizar um pivot para listar em colunas para realizar a soma e subtração mas sem sucesso, não consigo adicionar as colunas do pivot no select para realizar essas operações. Se tiver uma forma de fazer ou outra melhor, Agradeço.

Imagem da saída select https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iz5h.jpg

```
SELECT

   FROM

   (
   
   SELECT

   TB1.CD_PRODUTO,
   TB1.DS_PRODUTO,
   TB1.TP_MVTO_ESTOQUE,
   TB1.QT_MOVIMENTACAO,
   TB1.DATA,
   TB1.ESTOQUE_ATUAL



   FROM

   (
   
   SELECT 

   ITMVT.CD_PRODUTO,
   PROD.DS_PRODUTO,
   MVT.TP_MVTO_ESTOQUE,
   ITMVT.QT_MOVIMENTACAO,
   To_Char(ITMVT.DH_MVTO_ESTOQUE,'MM') AS DATA,
   Sum(EP.QT_ESTOQUE_ATUAL) AS ESTOQUE_ATUAL

   FROM

   ITMVTO_ESTOQUE ITMVT,
   PRODUTO PROD,
   MVTO_ESTOQUE MVT,
   EST_PRO EP

   WHERE

   ITMVT.DH_MVTO_ESTOQUE BETWEEN To_Date ('19/12/2020 23:59:59','DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss') AND
    To_Date ('26/12/2020 23:59:59','DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss') AND PROD.CD_PRODUTO = ITMVT.CD_PRODUTO AND
   PROD.CD_ESPECIE = 1 AND ITMVT.CD_MVTO_ESTOQUE = MVT.CD_MVTO_ESTOQUE AND
   MVT.TP_MVTO_ESTOQUE IN ('S','P','C','D') 
   AND EP.CD_PRODUTO = ITMVT.CD_PRODUTO

   GROUP BY ITMVT.CD_PRODUTO, PROD.DS_PRODUTO, ITMVT.QT_MOVIMENTACAO,
   ITMVT.DH_MVTO_ESTOQUE, MVT.TP_MVTO_ESTOQUE

   ORDER BY ITMVT.CD_PRODUTO

   

   )TB1

   ORDER BY TB1.CD_PRODUTO

   )TB2

    PIVOT (Sum(QT_MOVIMENTACAO) FOR TP_MVTO_ESTOQUE IN ('S','P','C','D'))
      
      ORDER BY 

      CD_PRODUTO
```

Comment: Tente algo como  ... Sum( (CASE WHEN   TP_MVTO_ESTOQUE IN ('S','P') THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) * EP.QT_ESTOQUE_ATUAL) ... o valor fica com o sinal